# Cannot listen and catch a tauri global event between two vue file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, frontend, tauri

I want to realize a small program where:

1. The first vue component "Start.vue" with the click of a button will pop up a new window
2. New window is composed of another "Playboard.vue".
3. "Start.vue" will also send initialziation parameters filled by users toward "Playboard.vue"

I use tauri's emit and listen API. However, by a lot of console logging, I found that although "Start.vue" did emit `"parameter-init"` event, the otherside cannot catch the event and the the loading process of "Playboard.vue" is just stuck there.

The code is as following:

**"Start.vue"**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
import { winConfig, Windows } from "./Window";
import { emit, listen } from "@tauri-apps/api/event";
import { parameterConfig } from "./Parameters"

const displayWindow: winConfig = {
    label: 'playBoard',
    others: {
      // some window parameters
    }
}
const w = ref("");
const h = ref("");
const m = ref("");

var windows: Windows = new Windows();
windows.listen();

async function start() {
  const params: parameterConfig = {
    width: w.value,
    height: h.value,
  }
  await emit("tauri-win-create", displayWindow)
  await emit("parameter-init", params)
}

</script>

<template>
  <div class = "container" id="startarea">
    <div class = "container" id="inputarea">
      <p><input id="greet-input" v-model="w" placeholder="Width" /></p>
      <p><input id="greet-input" v-model="h" placeholder="height" /></p>
      <p><input id="greet-input" v-model="m" placeholder="number of mines" /></p>
    </div>
    <div id="clickarea">
      <button type="button" @click="start" >Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Playboard.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Display from "./components/Display.vue";
import { listen, emit } from "@tauri-apps/api/event";
import { Parameter } from "./components/Parameters"
var params: Parameter = new Parameter();
params.listen();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <Display :width="params.width" :height="params.height"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Window.ts**

```
import { WebviewWindow, appWindow, getAll, WindowOptions } from '@tauri-apps/api/window'
import { emit, listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event'

export type winConfig = {
    label: string,
    others: WindowOptions
}

export class Windows {
    mainWin!: WebviewWindow;

    getWin(label: string) {
        return WebviewWindow.getByLabel(label)
    }

    getAllWin() {
        return getAll()
    }

    async createWin(options: winConfig) {
        let label = options.label
        let args: WindowOptions = options.others
        console.log(args)

        const existWin = getAll().find(w => w.label == label)
        if(existWin) {
            if(existWin.label.indexOf('main') == -1) {
                await existWin?.unminimize()
                await existWin?.setFocus()
                return
            }
            await existWin?.close()
        }

        let win = new WebviewWindow(label, args)
        
        win.once('tauri://created', async() => {
            console.log('window create success!')
        })

        win.once('tauri://error', async() => {
            console.log('window create error!')
        })
    }

    async listen() {
        await listen<winConfig>('tauri-win-create', (event) => {
            console.log(event)
            this.createWin(event.payload)
        })
    }
}
```

**Parameters.ts**

```
import { listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event'
import { event } from '@tauri-apps/api'

export type parameterConfig = {
    width: string,
    height: string
} 

export class Parameter {
    width: number = 0
    height: number = 0

    init(p: parameterConfig) {
        this.width = Number(p.width)
        this.height = Number(p.height)
    }

    async listen() {
        await listen<parameterConfig>('parameter-init', (event) => {
            console.log(event.payload)
            this.init(event.payload)
        })
    }
}
```

1. I tried to emit from "Parameters.ts" and then waited for "Start.vue" to catch the "go-ahead" signal and then started emitting. Sort of a hand-shake style. However I am a near complete newbie at this and I do not totally understand what is going on with async/await.
2. I also tried to remove the listen part in "Playboard.vue" and replaced root props with static binding, which turned out to work properly. I assume the problem is just at async/await and emit/listen.

What is the root of this problem? And if possible, what is the best practice to realize such a functionallity?

Comment: I tried to emit from rust backend by `emit_all`. I wrapped the payload with a serialized struct. The program still didn't work. The vue component I wrote to detect event had no response whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Tauri events are designed to communicate between the front end and the backend. Not between fontend and frontend.

https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/events/

I don't know if there's a way to communicate between two windows without using the backend in rust, but you can create a tauri command and send the same payload from it, then listen from the other window.

Comment: I am trying to pass the information to backend using event like tauri should, and then forward it to another vue component by emit. However, this process seems rathre tricky, and I cannot call `emit_all` or `emit_to` on AppHandle even though I clone the payload from previous event and wrap it in a payload struct, with `Clone+serde::serialize` trait.

Comment: To pass information from the front to the backend, either use events (which also work the other way round) or use commands. The advantage of commands is that tauri automatically deserializes the payload (provided it implements deserialization). If you use events, as shown in the [doc](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/src/tauri/event.rs.html#52) , an event just represents a &str, so you have to deserialize it yourself.

Comment: I think what's wrong with your code is that you're trying to emit the `event.payload` directly. Without it being directly deserialized. Is that it?